# Consulta en SQL que me devuelva información de una tabla con selección múltiple

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos llamada Categories, en ella estan 7 diferentes categorias( artes, deportes, farandula....,etc)

El usuario puede escoger las categorías de su preferencia(minimo 2) , y a partir de allí se muestran una serie de preguntas, algo así como una trivia.

Antes funcionaba excelente porque solo se escogía 1 sola categoría y esa la mandaba como parámetro a la consulta de mi base de datos donde me mostraba las preguntas correspondientes a esa id. Algo así:

```
"SELECT * FROM quenstions WHERE cod_categories = " + categories.id
```

Ahora como son varias ID's que se seleccionaran y según la elección del usuario(utilizo checkbox para eso), no se como implementar esa consulta!!! Cabe destacar que estoy utilizando Mysql y Java para realizar esto.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de variable/s conitienen los diferentes ID? string, array, ...?

Comment: puedes agrupar los `ids` en un un `String` separados por comas y hacer la condición con `in` del siguiente modo:  `cod_categories in( " +stringDeIds+")` para que quede algo así: `cod_categories in(2,4,7)`. Otra opción bastante peor  sería concatenar `AND`s a la where.

Comment: Probare eso de guardarlos en un String y ya les cuento si me funciono!! Gracias!

Comment: No conviene de ningún modo que pases directamente a la consulta valores provenientes de una fuente externa cualquiera. En una aplicación, cualquier usuario de nivel inferior con ciertas habilidades podría acceder a áreas para las que no tiene permiso, podría obtener datos o recursos del sistema o modificarlos y en una aplicación web tu sistema puede ser hackeado mediante técnicas de *Inyección SQL*. Tienes que blindar el código mediante consultas preparadas. Para el caso de `IN`, puedes hacerlo como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420956/5587982).

Answer (score 3):

Lo ideal sería que usaras IN, y dentro de los () añadieras cada id separado por comas

```
"SELECT * FROM quenstions WHERE cod_categories IN (" + ID1 + "," + ID2 + ")"
```

**EDITADO**

Con PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM quenstions WHERE cod_categories IN (?)");
Array arrayIDS = statement.getConnection().createArrayOf("tipoDeValor", new Object[]{ID1, ID2}); // Ahí pondrías el tipo de valor, INTEGER, VARCHAR o lo que necesites, al igual que las variables ID1 e ID2
statement.setArray(1, arrayIDS);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Coincido con el uso de IN, pero como dice @A. Cedano, lo suyo es usar consultas preparadas para evitar inyección de SQL. ¿Podrías editar la respuesta para mostrar como hacerlo con PreparedStatement?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `in`, tal que así:

```
"SELECT * FROM quenstions WHERE cod_categories in (" + categories.id + ")"
```

Comment: Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas.